# How do I survive falling into quicksand?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-oceancraft

In Oceancraft a new block is called quicksand which you slowly sink into until you start being dealt 1 heart of damage per second.

It kills quick - is there anyway I could maybe prevent myself from experiencing this horrible death?

Comment: Can you dig the quicksand out from under you?

Comment: @SaintWacko Not fast enough to save myself.

Comment: Does a potion of regeneration make it so you have time to dig yourself out? I'm assuming eventually you 'hit the bottom', and from there all you need to do is mine the block in front of you for you to be able to breath again.

Comment: @fredley The problem is there might be no bottom. Some quick sand pits are 3 blocks deep and some are 50.

Comment: ...in which case there's still a bottom

Comment: @fredly But you'll die of suffocation before you hit the bottom of that 50 block pit, even if you had a regen potion. A regen potion II only regenerates a half a heart every 1.25 seconds and according to the OP, the quicksand deals 1 heart every 1 second.

Comment: @aman207 Simple: just make more regen potions!

Comment: @TheBird956 Yeah it is a dup. I didn't seem to find the first question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I've escaped quicksand in the past is to dig the block in front of me, and the block below that, and push forward. As you sink into the quicksand you will move forward until you pop out onto the block next to it. If you don't manage to do this the first time, continue by digging the block below the ones you've already dug, and push your way out then. This should be enough to free you even with just a simple stone shovel.

Answer (score 2):

Always keep Enderpearls on your hotbar and throw them before you are suffocated.

Comment: Does it work when you are 'in' quicksand?

Comment: Ender Pearls don't work when you are in quicksand.

Answer (score 1):

Get a good shovel with efficiency and a helmet with aqua affinity to increase the speed at which you can mine the quicksand from under you.